# How to recognize an input of numbers and letters

Tags: java

I've fixed my code so that it recognizes if their's 4 digits and less or 6 digits and higher but now I want to know whether or not it contains letters within the numbers.

The code below detects the letters and prints the line I want only when I input 5 letters, and I want it to detect even if their's more digits than letters or more letters than digits.

```
    String digit;
    String regex;
    String regex1;
    regex = "[0-9]{5}";
    regex1 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}";
    String test;
    String validLength= "5";
    char one, two, three, four, five;
    {
    System.out.println("In this game, you will have to input 5 digits.");        
    do
    {
    System.out.println("Please input 5-digits.");
    digit = console.next();
    test = digit.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
    if (digit.matches(regex))
    {
    one = (char)digit.charAt(0);
    two = (char)digit.charAt(1);
    three = (char)digit.charAt(2);
    four = (char)digit.charAt(3);
    five = (char)digit.charAt(4);
    System.out.println((one + two + three + four + five) / 2 );
    }
    else if (test.length() > 5 || test.length() < 5)
        {
            System.out.println("You have letters in there.");
        }
    else if (digit.matches(regex1))
    {
       test = digit.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
       System.out.println("You have letters in there.");
    }
    else 

    if (digit.length() < 5)
        {
            System.out.println("You don't have enough digits.");
        }
        else if (digit.length() > 5)
        {
            System.out.println("You have to many digits.");
        }
} while (!digit.matches(regex));
```

Comment: Why are you casting `charAt()` to a `char`?

Comment: I want to seperate all the numbers so i can output the sum.


`System.out.println((one + two + three + four + five) / 2 );`

Comment: And what do you think [`charAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) returns?

Comment: charAt(0) returns the first digit of the numbers inputted.
Up to 5, because i only want 5.
If their's 5 digits, the sum will be calculated and therefore proceed to exit the system.
If their's less than 5 or more than 5, the program will loop and tell wether you have to many or less. Now my problem is, i want it to recognize the letters in the input, what's going on at the moment is that, `test` is replacing all the letters to nothing, therefore leaving only numbers to the test value. 
I want to take the test value and match it to regex but it's not working and this is the closest i've got.

Comment: No `charAt()` returns the `char` which represents the first digit in the `String` that is `digit`. You're basically saying with your code =>
`char one = (char)(char)` considering that `charAt()`, as the link I've provided says, returns a `char`, hence **`char`**`At()`!

Comment: Yes, the charAt(0) represents the first digit and therefore making it into a char value.

Comment: Follow the link my friend; you're arguing a moot point. You're casting a char into a char, i.e; it's needless.

Comment: How do i fix that than?

Comment: You simply don't do `(char)` - the cast - because it already is a `char`. You also have some things out of logical order or they are outright wrong, but I don't know what your main goal is. Why create all those chars for one calculation? Send the string to another function who's purpose it is to sum the digits and return the value. You do understand that adding `chars` is not the same thing as adding decimal digits; right? 
This -> `test.length() > 5 && test.length() < 5`??, can a number be greater && less than 5??

Comment: My goal is to, when 5-digits is inputted, to extract all 5 of them and calculate the sum.
I know that i could do it with `value1 = value / 10000;` `value = value % 10000;` and etc until 1.
That was a prototype, i'm still looking into that. The test value was the output of the rest of the input when you take off all the letters, therefore if it is bigger than 5 or smaller than 5, it would be true and output the else if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't go into regex here because honestly I think there is some misunderstandings that should be dealt with far before the road of niceties is undergone; plus, I'm no expert and I personally think they are more like rights of passage.

Anyway, let's start from the beginning, or at least when you determine they've entered a valid `digit`,

`if (digit.matches(regex))`.

Let's say...

```
String digits = "12345";
System.out.println(getSum(digits) / 2);
```

where...

```
public int getSum(String digits) {
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i = sum; i < digits.length(); i++) {
    sum += digits.charAt(i);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Same as your `System.out.println((one + two + three + four + five) / 2 );`.

> I hope the output of 127 makes you smile.

Going out on a limb, and since you didn't speak of the "char" value sum that, you expected it to treat your `char`s as decimal digits. Well, that would result in `7`. I only guess because of the whole `(char)charAt()` thing. This -> `(char)charAt()` sort of shows a lack of understanding that would make the use of regex highly questionable, IMHO of course.

Beyond that `else if (test.length() > 5 && test.length() < 5)`. This says, "if test's length is greater AND less than 5"! Without using some mathematical paradox, tell me that number.

So, on to your question -

> but now i want to know whether or not it contains letters within the
>   numbers.

well let's look at how finding out if any non-digit exists *might* be done - without regex so we can understand it...

```
public boolean containsNonDigits(String digits) {
    for(int i = 0; i < digits.length(); ++i) {
        if(Character.isDigit(digits.charAt(i))) {
            continue;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This says, "if the character is a digit keep going; everything's fine, otherwise false".

The other "question" -

> i want it to detect even if their's more digits than letters or more
>   letters than digits.

is an "additive" to the method above so I'll leave that one to you.

Comment: Thank you for responding, helped a lot, i will post the final code after i recode it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Charachter.isDigit(char)` and `Charachter.isLetter(char)` methods.

Here code sample that implements what you asked:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("In this game, you will have to input 5 digits.");
    int validLength = 5;
    boolean valid = false;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!valid)
    {
        System.out.println("Please input 5-digits.");
        String digit = console.next();
        if (digit.length() != validLength)
        {
            //if length not valid, mark as not valid and return to next iteration
            valid = false;
            String message = digit.length() < validLength ? "You don't have enoght digits." : "You have to many digits.";
            System.out.println(message);
            continue;
        }
        //here digit.length = 5
        int nDigits = 0,nLetters = 0,sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < digit.length(); i++)
        {
            Character ch = digit.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(ch))
            {
                nDigits++;
                sum += Integer.parseInt(ch.toString());
            }
            else if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                nLetters++;
            }
        }
        if (nLetters == 0           /* no letters */
                ||                  /* and */   
            nDigits == validLength  /* all chars are digits */)
        {
            System.out.println(sum/2);
            valid = true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You have letters in there.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, help a lot, i will post the final version after i re code it. I have a question though, why the `Character ch` what does character represent.

Comment: Does it represent `Char`? it would seem so, but i'm entirely sure.

Comment: yes it represent char. This class have some usefull static method as isDigit, isLetter etc.